# c language interpretation, involves integer calculation

Tags: c

I have the following code,

```
void main(void) {
    char x = 1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 - 1;
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

I get the result `-1`

However, `1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2`, already gets `-128`. Can you explain why I can successfully run the code above and get the result `-1`?

Also, is this an example of integer negation or overflow?

Comment: in many of implementation, `char` is by default signed type.

Comment: According to the C standard, `void` isn´t the right return type of `main`. It shall be an integer-compatible type or of course an `int`.

Answer (score 6):

`1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2` is `int` math with a product of 256.
`1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 - 1` is 255.

So code is like

```
char x = 255;
printf("%d", x);
```

If a `char` is an *unsigned* `char` with the range of 0...255, the output is

```
 255
```

If a `char` is a *signed* `char` with the range of -128...127, the assignment converts the 255 in an *implementation defined* manner to a `char` - likely a wrap around<sup>1</sup> (or 255 - 256) with a value of -1.  The output is

```
-1
```

`char` is implemented as an *unsigned* `char` or *signed* `char`.
In OP's case, it is a *signed* `char`.
A *signed* `char` has the same range, size, encoding as `signed char`, yet is a distinct type.

---

> is this an example of integer negation or overflow?

Neither.  It is an example of an *implementation defined* conversion.  And a very common one at that.

> Conversions .... Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.  C17dr § 6.3.1.3 3

---

<sup>1</sup> Conceptually with 2's complement encoding, the least significant byte  pattern of  `int` 255 or 0000...0000_1111_1111<sub>2</sub> is preserved as *signed* `char` where the lead bit is a sign (or -128 place).

Comment: Is integer warping the same as conversion?

Comment: "integer warping " is an example of a  conversion. In this case, from an `int` to a _signed_ `char`.   123.4 saved as an `char` is 123 is truncation, another form of conversion, from `double` to `char`.